# Suggestion to do close source my python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, obfuscation

I am new in python and pyqt5. I wrote a simple project by python and pyqt5 and now i want to close source code to not seen my source code. I think by `obfuscate` i can do this so i have installed `pyminifier`.

```
sudo apt install python-setuptools
pip3 install pyminifier
```

In my project i have a few class. By this command i can `obfuscate`  one class of my project:

```
pyminifier --obfuscate --gzip MainWindow.py 
import zlib, base64
exec(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eJytVU1v2zAMvftXaLnUGQJtl10G+NAmHbAObfPRIAWGwVBtylZrS64k56PYj59oO46dpNtlh8QW+UQ9PlI01yonS3HLhF.....
```

The above output is shown in my terminal after running `pyminifier --obfuscate`.

Does it commend must be run for each class and copy output code to other new file?

If i do, I think these class's that imported together properly do not known each other and finally application do not be run!!! I am right?

> Edit

I obfuscate entrypoint of my project by this command:

```
pyminifier --obfuscate --gzip Main.py
import zlib, base64
exec(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eJzLzC3ILypRKK4s5sqyBZJ6qRWZJVzuYGZiUXoZV1pRfq5CQGVgialeYEl4Zkp6akmxQiZEV6BjQUFOZnJiSWZ+HkShb2JmXnhmXkp+OUwNQgSomMvHFlmPhrsmV6UtigoNTa4sDR+gK1KTNTQ1uQAalDgb')))
# Created by pyminifier (https://github.com/liftoff/pyminifier)
```

and i copied this codes into other file.py and  i run app but i got Error:

```
python new.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 2, in <module>
    exec(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eJzLzC3ILypRKK4s5sqyBZJ6qRWZJVzuYGZiUXoZV1pRfq5CQGVgialeYEl4Zkp6akmxQiZEV6BjQUFOZnJiSWZ+HkShb2JmXnhmXkp+OUwNQgSomMvHFlmPhrsmV6UtigoNTa4sDR+gK1KTNTQ1uQAalDgb')))
  File "<string>", line 8
    j(L.exec())
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: PyQt5 is irrelevant in this case

Comment: Dude What does mean `PyQt5 is irrelevant in this case`? @eyllanesc

Comment: My project can have many dependencies but if I have a problem it does not imply that I will place all the tags related to my dependencies. In your case you want to obfuscate a code and it is not influenced by PyQt5, if it were another library it would be the same, unless your problem behaves differently just because you use PyQt5 but in your explanation you do not point that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running a Python 3 program with Python 2? The error message only makes sense if you are using Python 2, where `exec` was a keyword.

For obfuscating multiple files, see http://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/pyminifier.html:

> Pyminifier can now minify/obfuscate an arbitrary number of Python scripts in one go. For example, `./pyminifier.py -O *.py` will minify and obfuscate all files in the current directory ending in .py. To prevent issues with using differentiated obfuscated identifiers across multiple files, pyminifier will keep track of what replaces what via a lookup table to ensure foo_module.whatever is gets the same replacement across all source files. *Added in version 2.0*

Comment: Ops , u are right i used wrong python . By python3 new.py those problem gone

Comment: I have to run `pyminifier --obfuscate --gzip ` for each class? @ImperishableNight